# Representations $M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to B(H).$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

Consider the following fragment from Paulsen's book "Completely bounded maps and operator algebras". Here $M_n= M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are the complex $n \times n$ matrices.

[image]

How can we prove this? I tried the following: the subspaces are
$$\mathcal{K}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\pi(E_{i,i})\mathcal{K}.$$
However, are the spaces $\pi(E_{i,i})\mathcal{K}$ $n$-dimensional? I guess not, because otherwise $\mathcal{K}$ would be finite-dimensional and we can represent $M_n$ on an infinite-dimensional space. Hence, we need to look for other subspaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Structure of $*$-representations of matrix $C^*$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197751/structure-of-representations-of-matrix-c-algebras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subspaces $\pi(E_{jj})K$, $j=1,\ldots,n$, are pairwise isomorphic. This is because $\pi(E_{kj})$ is a linear isomorphism between $\pi(E_{jj})K$ and $\pi(E_{kk})K$. Let $\{f_r\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\pi(E_{11})K$. Now form, for each $r$,
$$K_r=\operatorname{span}\{\pi(E_{j1})f_r:\ j=1,\ldots,n\}.$$ Then $\dim K_r=n$, and $K=\bigoplus_rK_r$ (if we assume, as is usually done implicitly, that $\pi$ is non-degenerate). For any $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$,
\begin{align}
\pi(A)\bigg(\sum_jx_j\pi(E_{j1})f_r\bigg)
&=\pi\bigg(\sum_{a,b}A_{ab}E_{ab}\bigg)\bigg(\sum_jx_j\pi(E_{j1})f_r\bigg)\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_{a,b}A_{ab}x_b\pi(E_{a1})f_r\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_a\bigg(\sum_bA_{ab}x_b\bigg)\,\pi(E_{a1})f_r,
\end{align}
so $\pi(A)$ acts as the identity on $K_r$ (with the orthonormal basis chosen above).

Comment: I'm not sure how this shows that $\pi(A)$ acts as the identity on $K_r$. It looks like $\pi(A)$ does not even map $K_r$ into itself.

Comment: Yes, I had a couple of crucial typos. My bad.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Note that non-degeneracy is the same as asking that $\pi$ preserves the unit.

Comment: Also, what is $x_j$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm sure you knew this. But the OP might not. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @QuantumSpace: fair enough :)